Orthonormal basis for complex vector space
I have to answer the question with true or false: Every complex vector space with an inner dot product has an orthonormal basis.
I think it is false for the case $\dim V= \infty$. But i cant find a explaination for this.

Welcome to SE. This site is not here for us to solve your homework problems. You could however tell us your thoughts about the question such that we can tell you if you are on the right track or not. You could start out by adding additional context in your question e.g. what your definition of Basis in an infinite dimensional space is. Also, you should use MathJax to format your formulas (See my edit)

I dont have a definiton for a Basis of an infinite dimensional space. In this question i know that for finite dimension it is true because of the Gram–Schmidt_process.

it also depends if the dimension is countable or uncountable
